# SQL-problems with join

Tags: sql

I have three tables with students, employees and students. The column "City" in Employees and Students is an integer and is referring to the Table City where store a lot of cities.

[image]

Now I want a list of every person in the Employees and Students table with the city the person is located into.

For example:

```
   Name               | City 
   ---------------------------------
   James (Employee)   | London 
   Jesus (Student)    | London 
   Daniel (Employee)  | Manchester
```

Comment: next time show your sql code in the screenshot ;)

Comment: calling "City" your FK to City table is not a good idea. it would be better "CityID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, 'Employee' AS 'Role', c.City
 FROM Employees AS e
 INNER JOIN Cities AS c ON e.City = c.id
UNION ALL
SELECT Student, 'Student' AS 'Role', c.City
 FROM Students AS s
 INNER JOIN Cities AS c ON s.City = c.id
```

I would also suggest to change some field names:

- Table Students: Rename`Student` to `Name`
- Table Students: Rename `City` to `CityID`
- Table Employees: Rename `City` to `CityID`

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
SELECT e.Name + '(Employee)', c.City
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Cities c ON e.City = c.id
UNION ALL
SELECT s.Student + '(Student)', c.City
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Cities c ON s.City = c.id
```